# What was the size of the observable universe at the matter-dominated era and its mass density?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, estimation, observable-universe

For instance, at the scale factor $a=0.5$ and matter dominated era, what was the size of the observable universe and matter density?

Comment: You can find the answers here, if you're willing to squint at the plots closely enough: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/53121/47607 ($a=0.5$ corresponds to a time of about 6 billion years or $2\times 10^{17}$ seconds).